# When given a string, return an INT - MIPS

Tags: string, assembly, int, mips

i got one little doubt with my MIPS homework, i have to, given a string, return an int equal to the string (the string is made of ints). I have no idea how to do this, can anyone give me a boost?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that what you have to do is to convert a string to an integer in the way that atoi() does. You could have a look at an implementation of that function for hints.